# Is there a simple method to send goal for frontier_exploration?

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) on ROS Hydro Ubuntu 12.04 and using a pioneer p3dx to explore. I can successfully send exploration goals by clicking the publish point tool and drawing a polygon point by point, but its really troublesome to click the points to make the polygon for the next goal. Is there a simple method where I can just draw a rectangle? I do not understand how to do that in Rviz. Can someone help. Thanks

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198862/is-there-a-simple-method-to-send-goal-for-frontier_exploration?/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syafiqsalam](https://answers.ros.org/users/22212/syafiqsalam/) on 2015-04-19**:
can you share how to using frontier_exploration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Honestly, short of writing an RViz plugin, the 'Publish Point' tool is the easiest thing to do.  If you open the 'Tool Properties' panel, you can set the PP tool to not disable after each click, which would make it less frustrating.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check out this [question's](http://answers.ros.org/question/204382/frontier_exploration-to-do-unbounded-exploration/) answer.

---

Originally posted by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) with karma: 116 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1